# How to remove the older projects entries/list/history from the Visual Studio Opening Window?

Tags: visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022

All the Recently worked projects will be available in Visual Studio Opening window.
Even if the projects are removed from our file explorer, those names will exist in the VS Opening Window.

I'm able to delete those recent projects entries/history one at a time by using this option:

[image]

My Question is:

**How to delete all those history/entries at a time to see like the below window (screen)**?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I have posted the same question on [Super User](https://superuser.com/a/1723234/1695916) and that answer helped me to clear the recent projects history after opening the Visual Studio IDE**.

Also, while searching for this information, I learnt a lot from many other solutions like How many recent entries we have to keep when opened the VS and the other ways to delete them.
One of the references contains many ways to this issue is [C#Corner Article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/suthish_nair/remove-recent-projects-solutions-recent-files-find-and-replace-entries-from-visual-studio/).

But the **ClearRecent** extension in Visual Studio is a better solution as given in the above answer.

Answer (score 3):

Is not working with VS2022 though...

This might be a better solution to your problem.

Open powershell and navigate to "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE".
Then run the command .\devenv.exe /resetuserdata and the recent history data will be cleaned.